# More advanced version of Collections.frequency()

Tags: java, collections

So, let's imagine I have the following List:

```
List<Foo> myList = getListFromSomePlace();
int frequency = Collections.frequency(myList, someFoo);
```

This will count all `someFoo` matching elements.

However, if I have a more "complex" version:

```
List<Foo> myList = getListFromSomePlace();
int frequency = /* get number of Elements in the List whose getInternalFoo() match a certain value */
```

One way to do so would be to override the `equals`method in the Foo class, but I would really like to avoid putting custom behavior in the Foo class, specially because I might want to get frequency based on different properties from the Foo class, and I can only have one version of the overriden `equals` method.

Functions like `Collections.sort` would allow me to pass a custom Comparator that will do exactly what I need, but Collections.frequency doesn't provide this.

With Java8, I would use a stream and some Lambda expression to solve this issue, but I would like to see if there is a simple solution that will work with Java 7. I am looking for something that doesn't involve coding the custom frequency method myself, but using some existing API. Is there something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the standard JDK provides this (Java <= 7). If you want a solution that works with Java 7 and that doesn't involve coding, you can use Guava and its [`Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method.

It'll looks like this:

```
List<Foo> myList = getListFromSomePlace();
int frequency = Collections.frequency(Lists.transform(myList, new Function<Foo, MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public MyObject apply(Foo input) {
        return input.getInternalFoo();
    }
}), myCriteria);
```

If you still think it's not worth adding a third party library for this, you can still write your own Function interface, and a utility class that provide a method that transform a `List<T>` to a `List<U>` provided the mapping to apply. It's not very hard and won't take so many lines of code.

Writing your own implementation would permit you to do this in a single pass.

```
static <T, U> int frequency(Collection<T> coll, Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper, U criteria) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(coll);
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    Objects.requireNonNull(criteria);
    int frequency = 0;
    for(T t : coll) {
        if(criteria.equals(mapper.apply(t))) {
            frequency++;
        }
    }
    return frequency;
}
```

Comment: "Also this technique will require to iterate two times the list. One time to apply the mapping; and one time to check the frequency."  This is false; the transformation is done lazily and will only be done during the loop in the frequency implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh, yes you're absolutely right; thanks for the remainder.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer as the "Right Answer", however the other two answers also give interesting approaches. I selet this one because the Guava transform allows an implementation that is the most similar to what I'm looking for, specially because it does not involve any `hack`, `code duplication` nor more `boilerplate code`. Howerver, it does not mean that it has to be the most suitable solution for everyone or for every situation...

Comment: @Martin Yes, this is basically the closest translation you can have if you used the Stream API;
 `int frequency = myList.stream().map(Foo::getInternalFoo).filter(myCriteria::equals).count();`. However, I do like the answer with the `Comparator` alternative; which is nice too.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can avoid writing your own method.  Make it private if you don't want to pollute your API.

```
public static <T> int frequency(Collection<T> c, T o, Comparator<T> comp) {
    int freq = 0;
    for(T e : c) {
        if(o == null ? e == null : comp.compare(o, e) == 0) {
            ++freq;
        }
    }
    return freq;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, it's not like `frequency()` is a complicated method.

Answer (score 3):

Just 'decorate' your `someFoo` by overriding `equals()` as per your requirements:

```
List<Foo> myList = getListFromSomePlace();
final Foo someFoo = getSomeFooToGetItsFrequency();

int frequency = Collections.frequency(myList, new Foo() {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object another) {
        if (another == someFoo) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((another == null) || (someFoo == null)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (another.getClass() != someFoo.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Foo anotherFoo = (Foo) another;

        // Compare someFoo to anotherFoo as you wish here

        return comparisonResult;
    }
});
```

Now, this works because `Collections.frequency()` implementation checks if the object argument `equals()` every element of the list and not the other way round. If the latter were true, the returned frequency would be always `0`.

As you mentioned you 'might want to get frequency based on different properties from the Foo class', you could move the first part of the `equals()` method of the anonymous inner class to a generic abstract class:

```
public abstract class ComplexFrequency<T> {

    private final T self;

    public ComplexFrequency(T self) {
        this.self = self;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object another) {
        if (another == this.self) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((another == null) || (this.self == null)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (another.getClass() != this.self.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Let subclasses compare both objects
        return this.equals(this.self, (T) another);
    }

    protected abstract boolean equals(T self, T another);
}
```

Then, create a subclass of `ComplexFrequency` that compares as you wish:

```
public class FooComparingPropertyA extends ComplexFrequency<Foo> {

    public FooComparingPropertyA(Foo someFoo) {
        super(someFoo);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean equals(Foo self, Foo another) {
        // check equality based on propertyA
    }
}
```

And finally, 'decorate' your `someFoo` using this subclass and pass the 'decorated' instance to `Collections.frequency()`:

```
List<Foo> myList = getListFromSomePlace();
Foo someFoo = getSomeFooToGetItsFrequency();

int frequency = Collections.frequency(myList, new FooComparingPropertyA(someFoo));
```